# How can I get Finale and Audacity to work at the same time without one or the other app seemingly break?

Tags: windows-10, audio

I'm trying to use Finale and Audacity at the same time in Windows 10, but whenever I open Finale it breaks itself and Audacity if they are open at the same time, regardless of which one was open first.

Specifically, on Audacity as well as any other application that uses audio as well as video playback, makes it so nothing is played when the play button is pressed and it just sits there at 0.

I've had this happen with other applications before, and — if I recall correctly — I fixed it by using MME in one application and ASIO in the other. I should also mention I'm using an audio interface. I've tried using DirectSound (there is no MME option on Finale, and no ASIO option on Audacity) on both or making one use WASAPI to no avail. Audacity and etc stays broken after closing Finale.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to avoid the conflict by configuring Audacity to use one audio output device, and Finale another.

This is easily and cheaply achieved today, owing to the proliferation of USB audio adaptors, which have their own built-in soundcard.

If sound quality isn't that important at the point in your work when you're hitting the conflict, you may just want to drive a cheap set of desktop speakers from the second audio output. Otherwise you will need to connect the USB output to whatever gives the quality you need.

Alternatively, if you do not require audio output from one or other app at the point when you get the conflict, you may configure the app not to use the audio output, and resolve the conflict that way.

Answer (score 0):

One or both of the applications is probably grabbing an exclusive lock on the audio output device.

In the windows control panel look for the Sound settings.  In there, select the output device and click the properties button.  This will open the properties panel for the output device.  In there, look for the Advanced tab.  There you will see an item under Exclusive Mode titled "Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device."  Uncheck it and save the new settings.

Restart the applications and see if that helps.

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to have worked unfortunately...

Comment: If an exclusive audio lock wasn't the issue, then I would have to suspect some other incompatibility between the two apps.  One more thing to try would be running them as different users.  Ie. start one by simply clicking on it's icon and start the other by SHIFT-right-clicking and selecting "run as another user" or "run as administrator".  If it's a resource lock issue, maybe running as another user will allow two simultaneous uses of the underlying resource.  No promises... I'm a UNIX guy and only suffer with Windows when I have to.  Good luck!